# Pass a child to a specialized React component in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a code which looks like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Tooltip, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip title="Same text" arrow>
        <Button>One</Button>
      </Tooltip>
      <Tooltip title="Same text" arrow>
        <Button>Two</Button>
      </Tooltip>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-microservice-4e59z?file=/src/App.tsx:0-346

Since both Tooltips have exactly the same properties but different children, I would like to define a [specialized](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#specialization) component  and rewrite my code to something like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Tooltip, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

function MyTooltip(child: JSX.Element) {
  return (<Tooltip title="Same text" arrow>{child}</Tooltip>);
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyTooltip>
        <Button>One</Button>
      </MyTooltip>
      <MyTooltip>
        <Button>Two</Button>
      </MyTooltip>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-worker-xrqsq?file=/src/App.tsx

But this leads to a compilation error: `Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, keys(2739)` which I can't fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-bird-qj3b7?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
interface MyTooltipProps {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

const MyTooltip: React.FC<MyTooltipProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Tooltip title="Same text" arrow>
      {children}
    </Tooltip>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes, I linked the same article in my question :) 

Your solution works in JS but not in TS.

Comment: Marked your answer accepted since it has its benefits (consumers can't override title and arrow, which might be a good thing).

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice approach (**defaultProps**) which also allows overriding any Tooltip properties on MyTooltip:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Tooltip, Button, TooltipProps } from "@material-ui/core";

function MyTooltip(props: TooltipProps) {
  return <Tooltip {...props} />;
};

MyTooltip.defaultProps = {
  title: "Same text",
  arrow: true
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyTooltip arrow={false}>
        <Button>One</Button>
      </MyTooltip>
      <MyTooltip title="Overriden text">
        <Button>Two</Button>
      </MyTooltip>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/defaultprops-lythg?file=/src/App.tsx